# How to get product links

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I am trying to fetch the product links for a product, but all return as null or zero. Even though, the product links are shown on the admin UI.

1: Use ProductLinkRepositoryInterface

```
    $prdRepo = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface');
    if ($prdRepo) {
        $links = $prdRepo->getList($product);
        //This output as 0
        echo 'links='; echo count($links); echo PHP_EOL;
    }
```

2: Use ProductInterface, getProductLinks() method

```
$productLinks = $product->getProductLinks();
```

These two ways return 0.
I am not sure if it is the correct way to fetch the product links.

Comment: Hi @blue do have solution for this if you have can u share me please